# Image Renditions with a fixed width and a maximum height?

Tags: image-rendition

Is it possible to use the SharePoint image rendition with a fixed width and a maximum height?

Answer (score 0):

No,

You only have the option to either specify a height, a width or both when you create a new image rendition.

You would have to also use some CSS where the image is used for it to work (you could for example specify an image rendition as the background of a `div` with a fixed width and a maximum height)